# Advice on developing a android photo vault app - File locking in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, password-encryption

I am new to android programming, I have developed 2 very simple apps, one is a weather and other is a story app.

I am planning to develop a app similar to photo vault app. 
Similar to this - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enchantedcloud.photovault&hl=en

How complex is this? I am not able to find much information online to develop the app. Is there any way to copy over the files in the photo camera library to a new location and then hide them?

The app should basically do this:

```
1) Ask for a password, when user opens app. --> Easy DONE
2) Ask user permission to access the camera photo library --> Stuck :(
3) Let user select the pics he wants to copy and hide in the app --> Stuck :(
4) Copy these pics in a secret location? or encrypt them? --> Stuck need help here.
5) Save them and when the user needs access to them, ask for a pass and show them.
```

I am not planning to support videos yet, just hiding jpegs is good enough.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: will you please suggest something if you had solved this, bcz i have to do the same thing in my app.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have small hack over here. Try to get apk file of the above application and use Java decompiler(Kind of reverese Engineering) [Java Decomplier](http://jd.benow.ca/) to check what all java files how he organised it and what structure he followed and I am not sure that will decompile resource files even(xml) files. Hope it helps you a bit.